# How to get missing date in columns using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have following data frame in which i want to get missing date along with its keys in pandas.

```
     size     number     key      date
0  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181001
1  153.2 K    12345     No        20181001
2  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181003
3  153.2 K    12345     No        20181003
4  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181004
5  153.2 K    12345     No        20181004
```

I want the output as,

```
  key      date
  Hello     20181002
  No        20181002
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If the date is missing, how do you know the key, number and size? Also, you have not specified the problem you are facing in your code.

Comment: thats the problem, if i have 2 keys then the code should check for missing date for both @It_is_Chris

Comment: Okay, that doesn't make sense though. How do you know the other values for dates when observations were not taken?

Comment: oh sorry my bad, edited the question. so i want the key and date only @It_is_Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with some fancy reshaping like this:

```
(df.pivot('date', 'key')
   .reindex(np.arange(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max()+1))
   .stack('key', dropna=False)
   .loc[lambda x: x['size'].isna()]
   .index
   .to_frame(index=False))
```

Output:

```
       date    key
0  20181002  Hello
1  20181002     No
```

#### How?

- Reshape the dataframe such that you have a single date per row
- Next, reindex the dataframe to fill in missing dates
- Reshape the dataframe stacking key but keeping NaN values
- Filter dataframe to only missing values using `isna`
- Convert the index to a dataframe with to_frame

#### Update address date concern mentioned by @Cimbali below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
(df.pivot('date', 'key')
   .reindex(pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D'))
   .stack('key', dropna=False)
   .loc[lambda x: x['size'].isna()]
   .index
   .to_frame(index=False))
```

Output:

```
           0    key
0 2018-10-02  Hello
1 2018-10-02     No
```

Comment: This only works because the dates are all in the same month. Your `np.arange` will give you a lot of non-dates with last 2 digits > 31 as soon as you have more than 1.

Comment: @Great point, we can do something similiar convert date to datetime then using `pd.date_range`.

Comment: File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 456, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 350, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  @ScottBoston

Comment: Hrm... this looks like bad data in the df['date']  Maybe you have a value that isn't the same structure as %Y%m%d.  You can `coerce` and put NaN for not covertable strings like this: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')`

Comment: @ScottBoston can we calculate dates for each key separately? like Hello has date range from 20190101 to 20190120 and No has date range from 2019015 to 20190119

Comment: Yes, you can use groupby to do this functionality.

Comment: @ScottBoston where should i add it

Comment: @Gaurav Try this: `df.groupby('key').apply(lambda x: x.pivot('date','key').reindex(pd.date_range(x['date'].min(), x['date'].max(), freq='D'))
   .stack('key', dropna=False))`

Answer (score 1):

If we align the dates along one dimension, it becomes easier to see the common values (on the index) and where to fill (on the columns). We can do this with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html). (The `value` here is just a placeholder with all `1`s.)

```
>>> tab = df.assign(value=1).pivot_table(index='key', columns='date', values='value')
>>> tab
date   20181001  20181003  20181004
key                                
Hello         1         1         1
No            1         1         1
```

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) allows us to do the opposite transformation:

```
>>> tab.reset_index().melt(id_vars='key').drop(columns='value')
     key      date
0  Hello  20181001
1     No  20181001
2  Hello  20181003
3     No  20181003
4  Hello  20181004
5     No  20181004
```

So if we want an intermediate step to add missing dates, we should probably convert them to dates first and use `pd.date_range`:

```
>>> avail_dates = pd.to_datetime(tab.columns, format='%Y%m%d')
>>> avail_dates
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-01', '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
>>> all_dates = pd.date_range(avail_dates.min(), avail_dates.max(), freq='D')
>>> tab_filled = tab.reindex(all_dates.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int), axis='columns')
>>> tab_filled
       20181001  20181002  20181003  20181004
key                                          
Hello         1       NaN         1         1
No            1       NaN         1         1
```

Finally get only the new columns, and do our `melt` trick:

```
>>> missing = tab_filled.drop(columns=tab.columns).reset_index().melt('key').drop(columns=['value'])
>>> missing
     key  variable
0  Hello  20181002
1     No  20181002
```

---

Here’s a shorter variant on the same principle, where we first build the dates, then a synthetic dataframe that we can `melt`:

```
>>> dates = pd.date_range(
...     *pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d').agg(['min', 'max']), freq='D'
... ).strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
>>> dates
Int64Index([20181001, 20181002, 20181003, 20181004], dtype='int64')
>>> pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(df['key'].unique(), name='key'),
...              columns=dates.difference(df['date']))\
... .reset_index().melt('key').drop(columns=['value'])
     key  variable
0  Hello  20181002
1     No  20181002
```

Comment: >>> tab = df.assign(value=np.nan).pivot_table(index='key', columns='date', values='value')
this giving me empty dataframe @Cimbali

Comment: @Gaurav I meant `df.assign(value=1)` as mentioned in the explanation. Fixed it.

Comment: can we calculate dates for each key separately? like Hello has date range from 20190101 to 20190120 and No has date range from 2019015 to 20190119