# Get missing dates from datafrane pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I want to get missing dates for each keys in columns. my dataframe as follows,

```
     size     number     key      date
0  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181002
1  153.2 K    12345     No        20181001
2  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181003
3  153.2 K    12345     No        20181003
4  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181004
5  153.2 K    12345     No        20181005
6  153.2 K    12345     Hello     20181006
```

and i want to get following result

```
 key        date
  No        20181002
  No        20181004
  Hello     20181005
```

for key="No" there are no date 20181002, 20181004. what i am trying to say is for each key there is different date range and the output should be missing dates for each key in there specific date range

following code i have used but it takes dates of both keys and takes start date as 20181001 and end date as 20181006

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('4002.csv')
print(df.head(1))

dates = pd.date_range(*pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d',errors='coerce').agg(['min', 'max']), freq='D').strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(df['key'].unique(), name='key'),columns=dates.difference(df['date'])).reset_index().melt('key').drop(columns=['value'])
print(df1)
df1.to_csv('4002output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It seems there is a value for every date in your column. What is "missing" about them? I'm not sure I follow the logic to get your resulting dataframe.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Perhaps you can add a little more explanation adding to : *the date from which Hello started in that range result for hello should be shown, like startdate for Hello is 20181002 and for No its 20181001*

Comment: @jorf.brunning see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181630/how-to-get-missing-date-in-columns-using-python-pandas. questioner was asking basically for reindex

Comment: @jorf.brunning sorry i have edited the output, for key="No" there are no date 20181002, 20181004. what i am trying to say is for each key there is different date range and the output should be missing dates for each key in there specific date range

Comment: Why wouldn't you also get `Hello 20181001` and `No 20181006`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Because "Hello" date range starts with 20181002 and ends with 20181006 and  "No" date range starts with 20181001 and ends with 20181005, what i mean to say is for each key there will be different date range and i want to get dates for each key separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.groupby('key')['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['min'], x['max']), axis=1)
        .explode()
        .reset_index(),
    names=['key', 'date']
)

new_df = (df.set_index(['key', 'date'])
          .reindex(midx)
          .loc[lambda df_: df_['size'].isna()]
          .index
          .to_frame(index=False)
          .rename(columns={0: 'date'}))
```

`new_df`:

```
     key       date
0  Hello 2018-10-05
1     No 2018-10-02
2     No 2018-10-04
```

Optional convert dates back to strings:

```
new_df['date'] = new_df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

```
     key      date
0  Hello  20181005
1     No  20181002
2     No  20181004
```

---

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'size': ['153.2 K', '153.2 K', '153.2 K', '153.2 K', '153.2 K', '153.2 K',
             '153.2 K'],
    'number': [12345, 12345, 12345, 12345, 12345, 12345, 12345],
    'key': ['Hello', 'No', 'Hello', 'No', 'Hello', 'No', 'Hello'],
    'date': [20181002, 20181001, 20181003, 20181003, 20181004, 20181005,
             20181006]
})
```

Explanations:

1. [`Groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) `min` and `max` values per `key` group:

```
df.groupby('key')['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
             min        max
key                        
Hello 2018-10-02 2018-10-06
No    2018-10-01 2018-10-05
```

2. Turn this into a [`Date Range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df.groupby('key')['date'].agg(['min', 'max']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['min'], x['max']), axis=1)
```

```
key
Hello    DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-02', '2018-10-03', '20...
No       DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', '20...
dtype: object
```

3. [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) into multiple rows:

```
df.groupby('key')['date'].agg(['min', 'max']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['min'], x['max']), axis=1) \
        .explode()
 
key
Hello   2018-10-02
Hello   2018-10-03
Hello   2018-10-04
Hello   2018-10-05
Hello   2018-10-06
No      2018-10-01
No      2018-10-02
No      2018-10-03
No      2018-10-04
No      2018-10-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

4. Turn this frame into a [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html):

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.groupby('key')['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['min'], x['max']), axis=1)
        .explode()
        .reset_index(),
    names=['key', 'date']
)

MultiIndex([('Hello', '2018-10-02'),
            ('Hello', '2018-10-03'),
            ('Hello', '2018-10-04'),
            ('Hello', '2018-10-05'),
            ('Hello', '2018-10-06'),
            (   'No', '2018-10-01'),
            (   'No', '2018-10-02'),
            (   'No', '2018-10-03'),
            (   'No', '2018-10-04'),
            (   'No', '2018-10-05')],
           names=['key', 'date'])
```

The rest is borrowed from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182031/15497888) by @ScottBoston

5. [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the Multi-Index:

```
df.set_index(['key', 'date'])\
          .reindex(midx)

                     size   number
key   date                           
Hello 2018-10-02  153.2 K  12345.0
      2018-10-03  153.2 K  12345.0
      2018-10-04  153.2 K  12345.0
      2018-10-05      NaN      NaN
      2018-10-06  153.2 K  12345.0
No    2018-10-01  153.2 K  12345.0
      2018-10-02      NaN      NaN
      2018-10-03  153.2 K  12345.0
      2018-10-04      NaN      NaN
      2018-10-05  153.2 K  12345.0
```

6. Keep `NaN` rows with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.set_index(['key', 'date']) \
          .reindex(midx) \
          .loc[lambda df_: df_['size'].isna()]
 
                 size  number
key   date                      
Hello 2018-10-05  NaN     NaN
No    2018-10-02  NaN     NaN
      2018-10-04  NaN     NaN
```

7. Turn the remaining index into a [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html):

```
(df.set_index(['key', 'date'])
 .reindex(midx)
 .loc[lambda df_: df_['size'].isna()]
 .index
 .to_frame(index=False))

     key       date
0  Hello 2018-10-05
1     No 2018-10-02
2     No 2018-10-04
```